# Confluent CLI : not able to install in mac

Tags: macos, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I'm trying to set up Confluent CLI on my mac machine, I followed instructions given here https://docs.confluent.io/confluent-cli/current/install.html#cli-install.

After executing the `curl -sL --http1.1 https://cnfl.io/cli | sh -s -- latest` I am seeing below output.
[image]

When I try to execute confluent command later, I'm getting command not found.
[image]

Can anyone help me with what's going wrong here?

Comment: In my case my .zshrc file had the "export PATH" statement commented out. Might want to check that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It installed fine...

As the output says,

> `info: please ensure ./bin is in your PATH`

Or read the docs again, where it shows

```
export PATH=$(pwd)/bin:$PATH
```

---

You need to edit your `.zshrc` or `.bashrc` to add that folder where the binary was installed to your `PATH`

Or use `./bin/confluent` command directly from the folder it was installed to.